# Ticket reservation system built entirely on Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

Would it be possible to build a Ticketmaster style ticket reservation system by storing all information in a Cassandra cluster?

The system needs to be able to

```
1. Display the correct number of tickets available at one time
2. Temporarily reserve a ticket while the customer is making the purchase
3. No two users can ever buy the same ticket.
```

For consistency all reads and writes should be made at quorum.  I'm not sure how to implement steps 2 or 3?

Comment: Why would you? Although it's certainly possible, I do not really see any reason why you wouldn't use MySQL. It will be more expensive and you will have to manually control data relationships in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

However, there will be some transactions where you want strict consistency. For example, consistency does not matter when the user is browsing the site and adding tickets to their shopping cart, but when they checkout and select a specific seat number on a specific day consistency matters a great deal (double bookings being a bad thing, especially for high interest events).

So, you could implement 99% of the functionality in an eventually consistent database and implement the checkout process in a consistent database. This is also nice because you can scale 99% of your system that likely gets >70% of the load horizontally and across multiple data centers. Just keep in mind that you will have to deal with the scenario of your site being up but your checkout process being down (ex., an error dialog at checkout asking them to wait/retry and giving them a promo code for their troubles).

The last detail is that you will need to update your eventually consistent database's "number of available tickets" after someone checks out. The good news is that this can be done lazily - queue up that job and do it whenever your system has some spare cycles. It certainly never has to happen in the critical path of the user's checkout process.